# Showing random Product images from same category as the selected product is in. ROR app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, foreign-keys, many-to-many, paperclip

I'm modifying a Rails app I've been working on.

I installed a model `images.rb` to handle all images for products.

When the user has selected a product the user sees the product at `app/views/products/show.html.erb`

And at the bottom of the `show.html.erb` the app gives the user suggestions for similar product in the same category as the product the user is looking at.

Before I added the `image.rb`model to handle the images each product had one picture attached to it and every thing worked, but now I'm getting an error.  Below is the code I used to display the random products in the same category:

the `show.html.erb`

```
 <div class="row product-teaser">
  <h4 class="text-center teaser-text"> similar products to <%= @product.title %> : </h4>
   <% @products_rand.each do |product| %>
      <div class="col-sm-2 col-xs-3 center-block product-thumbs-product-view" >
            <%= link_to product_path (product) do %>
                <%= image_tag @product.image.url, :size => "100%x100%", class: "img-responsive center-block" %>
            <% end %>  
          <h5 class="text-center"><%= link_to product.title, product, class: "text-center" %></h5>    
      </div>
    <% end %>   
  </div>
```

And in the `products_controller.rb`  `show` method I had this variable to fetch the random products from the same category.

```
class ProductsController < ApplicationController
before_action :set_product, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]

  def show    
     @products_rand = Product.where(category_id: @product.category_id).order("RANDOM()").limit(6)
  end

private
   # Use callbacks to share common setup or constraints between actions.
  def set_product
    @product = Product.find(params[:id])
  end

  # Never trust parameters from the scary internet, only allow the white list through.
  def product_params
    params.require(:product).permit(:title, :description, :price_usd,  :image, :category_id, :stock_quantity, :label_id, :query, :slug, images_attributes: [:image , :id , :_destroy])
  end
 end
```

After I added the `image.rb` I always get this error: `undefined method 'url' for "":String` when trying to load the show page.  The error is appearing in this line: `<%= image_tag @product.image.url, :size => "100%x100%", class: "img-responsive center-block" %>`

the `product.rb`model

```
class Product < ActiveRecord::Base
  acts_as_list :scope => [:category, :label]
  belongs_to :category
  belongs_to :label

  has_many :images
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :images
  has_many :product_items, :dependent => :destroy

    validates :title, :description, presence: true
    validates :price_usd, :price_isl, numericality: {greater_than_or_equal_to: 0.01}
    validates :title, uniqueness: true  
 end
```

the `image.rb`model

```
class Image < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :product
    has_attached_file :image, styles: { medium: "500x500#", thumb: "100x100#" }
    validates_attachment_content_type :image, content_type: /\Aimage\/.*\z/
 end
```

I'm not sure what to do, can someone advise me?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your `Product has_many :images` then `@product.image.url` is not going to work.

`@product.images.sample` will give you a random image for that product.

It looks like you're using `Paperclip`, which you have configured to add an `image` attachment to your `Image` model, so you need to add an extra method to your chain:

`@product.images.sample.image.url` will retrieve the URL for the image attachment of a randomly selected `image` association.

`@product.image` is currently returning an empty string, so you must have an `image` column on your `products` table of type `string` or `text`, or an `image` method on your model. If you don't need it anymore then you should remove it.

If it's a column in your table, in a migration file:

```
def change
  remove_column :products, :image
end
```

#### Edit

As suggested by MrYoshiji, getting a random image would be more efficiently achieved at the database level, especially if a product has a lot of associated images. A scope method on the `Image` model would do the trick, along with a `Product` method to abstract it and simplify your view.

```
class Image < ActiveRecord::Base
  scope :random, -> { order("RANDOM()").limit(1) }
end

class Product < ActiveRecord::Base
  def random_image
    images.random.take
  end
end
```

Then in your view

```
@product.random_image.image.url
```

Comment: thanks for the answer @m. simon borg,  at an other part of the `show.htlm.erb` I'm using this code and it works: `<% @product.images.each do |image_product| %>
  <%= image_tag image_product.image.url(:medium), class: "img-responsive" %>
<% end %>`

Comment: Thanks, updated the answer now that I know it should be `has_many` @DaudiHell

Comment: thanks for the update, I see what you mean, but, now I'm getting this error: `undefined method `url' for #<Image:0x007fe0bed88a28>`

Comment: Updated the answer. Saw that you're configuring Paperclip to add an `image` attachment to the `Image` model. So to get an image's URL it would be `image.image.url`, not `image.url` @DaudiHell

Comment: the random logic can be done on the DB level instead of calling `Array#sample`, it would save some performances (depending on how many a `Product` has `images`)

Comment: @MrYoshiji You're right, I added that to the answer